# How to make a proper if-else statement given multiple rules to run the program

Tags: java, if-statement

Hello  i need to invent a baccarat game.. now on top of that there are rules given that i need to follow to make the game successful. the problem is im getting confused with my if-else statement. Idk which should come first. and which shouldnt. sometimes when i run it it looks good but when i run it several times with different random numbers being produced, it seems like none of my if-else statement works( under the //rules section). Please help!

EDITED:(new //rules)

```
  //rules
       if(sumPlayer > 7 && sumPlayer <10) {
          System.out.println ( " Natural! No cards are drawn. "); 
       } else if (sumPlayer <6){
          System.out.println ( " Player must draw to a hand of 5 or less." + 
                          "\nPlayer draws a third card: " +c3+ " .");
       } else if(c3 > 5){
          System.out.println ( " Player stands a pat. ");
       } else {
          System.out.println ( " Player's hand is now : " +sumC3+ " .");
       }
```

Comment: Always provide well-formatted code. People are here to help, so be kind towards their eyes. This time I fixed that for you.

Comment: oh okay sorry.. my bad im still learning to use this site.. thanks btw

Comment: I think what you first need to learn is, Java program runs sequentially. After you get pass the whole bunch of if statement, it won't magically get re-evaluated unless you have some kind of loop etc.  I think it is better if you can use an IDE, open the debugger, follow the execution and keep your eye on different variables involved.  You may get better understand on how the program actually works

Answer (score 0):

You want to deal with the player and dealer's hands separately.  In a series of if/else decisions, only one branch can ever be selected.  This means the conditions tested inside a set of if/else statements should be mutually exclusive.  If you test conditions of your hand, and then the dealers hand, those two conditions may both be possible at the same time, but if/then code can't handle both.

Here's some pseudocode that illustrates this:

```
if(test my hand 1) {
    do something with my score
} else if(test my hand 2){
    do something with my score
} else if(test my hand 3){
    do something with my score
} else {
    do a default thing with my score
}

if(test dealer hand 1) {
    do something with dealer score
} else if(test dealer hand 2){
    do something with dealer score
} else if(test dealer hand 3){
    do something with dealer score
} else {
    do a default thing with dealer score
}
```

By the way - when you show which player wins, you might want to show the score too.  It's good for debugging and also nice to let the user know how well they played.

Comment: hey i have tried doing what u said.. its in my question, edited section. tell if i did it right and if no, give me comments on how to re-do it. thank you.

Comment: The key thing to remember about a string of if/elses is that only one of them will be chosen.  If the first condition is met, all the rest as skipped.  It looks to me like your revised rules may still expect several conditions of the if/else to be met and executed.  You can also put as many lines of code between if statements as you need, as long as they are surrounded by {}.  Other than that, you have broken up your decision logic much better.  You understand the rules, so run through as many scenarios as you can think of and test.  Test random values and also set some specific data to test.